# how to create empty folder on google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to create empty folder for my android app..

```
File body = new File();

body.setTitle("title");

java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("title");

FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.google-apps.folder", fileContent);

File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

This doesnt seem to work.....

Getting exception:

java.io.FileNotFoundException:/title open failed ENOENT ( no such file or directory)

Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (no such file or directory)

Comment: Next time you have a car issue please phone the mechanics and tell them my car doesn't seems to work please fix it. If you have an issue, the first cool thing would be to tell what happen... Nothing? The app crash? an error message?

Comment: Solved...

File body = new File("title");

body.setTitle("title");

body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();

It will create folder named "title" in google drive.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved...

```
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("title");
body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
```

It will create folder named **title** in google drive.

Comment: File body = new File(); //the constructor does not take a string

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, I get "Insufficient permission [403]" error