# Create a new folder and insert files in that folder. Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I want to create a hidden folder in user's Google drive root directory and then want to insert some text files in that folder and later want to retrieve that files. I tried the quick guide and files are uploading fine but in the root directory and files are visible to user. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884943/how-to-create-empty-folder-on-google-drive) I know how to create an empty folder. . But from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/insert) I do not understand how to use that code to insert the file in a particular folder.

So my Question is how to create hidden folder and perform CURD operations on files using drive API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `appdata` folder. See here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata

Comment: Great Thanks Paul. Exactly what I was looking for. But Is there any method which can make a typical folder hidden?

Comment: I'm not sure but remember reading that "hidden" doesn't really mean what you'd expect in Drive.

Comment: Ok Thanks! One more question though, Is it possible to share the files in `app data` folder to multiple users? I mean If a user want to share the `app data` folder files to any one then Is it possible to just make duplicate of these files to other user drive `app data` folder?

Comment: Let say I have an option of sharing files in my app. When user select that option a list of his/her gmail friends will open. From there he/she can choose the users which he want to share files. and after choosing his/her friends the files will automatically appear in `app data` folder of his/her friends