# Google Drive can't access data from another device

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

Ok I have two device both have same gmail account and both have a same app but signed with different keys. SHA1 Keys are configured in Google console.

I am uploading some text files from one device and want to import these files in another device. Now I can upload the files and also get the files in same devices but not able to get uploaded files from another device. The result is empty, However there is no error in log cat.

If I upload files from second devices then I can import these file only from second device. So the problem is importing the files only works from the device which upload the files.

I want to get files no matter from which device I am uploading.

Note - In Google drive app it shows all files no matter from which device the files are uploaded.

Here is the code

```
private List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = service.files().list();

        do {

            try {
                FileList files = request.execute();

                result.addAll(files.getItems());
                request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
            } catch (final UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);

                request.setPageToken(null);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),
                                REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                    }
                });


                break;
            }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null
                && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

        Log.v("result", result.toString());
        return result;
    }
```

### Update

Here is the auth code

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    String accountName = preferences.getString("accountName", "");
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,
            Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
    if (accountName.equals("")) {

        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),

        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    } else {
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
        service = getDriveService(credential);

    }
```

Comment: What Drive scope are you using?

Comment: I have not set any scope for the app.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you ask for authorisation

Comment: You're using drive.file scope ("DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE"). Try changing it to drive scope and see what happens. If it works with drive scope, it means Drive is seeing your two devices as two different apps, probably because they have two different client ids.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you so much. Now app is working fine. https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/DriveScopes.html Can you write an answer so that I can accept that?

Comment: also if you don't mind can you answer my one more question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115087/create-a-new-folder-and-insert-files-in-that-folder-google-drive . Question is in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because your two devices are being seen by Drive as two different apps. Because you're using Drive.File scope, each app can only see files that it created itself. Either you need to give both apps the same ID, or use Drive scope so each app can see all files.